CDI annotations @Kbase and @Kcontainer in Drools 8?
I would like to migrate an application using Drools 7 to Drools 8.
I was using some CDI annotations (@Kbase and @Kcontainer) through Maven dependency: org.drools:drools-cdi.
While looking at the official migration guide (https://docs.drools.org/latest/drools-docs/drools/migration-guide/index.html) I cannot see anything related to these annotations. At the same time, there is no more "drools-cdi" dependency for Drools 8.
Are these annotations deprectated/removed? Is it documented somewhere? What should be the proper way to replace them?
Thank you
